# Unresolved reference async in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to perform network operation async in `Kotlin`. I read it you can do async using `async` function. I am getting below error, can anyone guess what could be the issue ?

> Unresolved reference: async

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    async() {
        val forecastWeather = ForecastRequest("302015").execute()
        Log.d("Test", forecastWeather.toString())
    }
}
```

**ForecastRequest.kt**

```
class ForecastRequest(val zipcode: String) {
    companion object {
        private val APP_ID = "XYZ"
        private val URL = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/" +
                    "forecast/daily?mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7"
        private val COMPLETE_URL = "$URL&APPID=$APP_ID&q="
    }

    fun execute(): ForecastResponse {
        val forecastJsonStr = java.net.URL(COMPLETE_URL + zipcode).readText()
        return Gson().fromJson(forecastJsonStr, ForecastResponse::class.java)
    }
}
```

Top level **build.gradle**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-4'
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0-alpha2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Module level **build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.williams.thirddemo"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
}
```

Comment: You've accidentally (?) posted your APP_ID here. You should disable it now and get a new one, unless this API also requires an API secret.

Comment: @ChristianBrüggemann Ah, removed :)

Comment: @Williams it is still historically in the change log for the question, so change it if you don't want some illicit use of your APP_ID

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see `async` function is available in `anko` library not `Kotlin` library itself. https://github.com/Kotlin/anko

I resolved by adding this dependency in build.gradle `compile "org.jetbrains.anko:anko-commons:0.10.1"` as this is not available in Kotlin itself.

I see that `async` is deprecated now, library suggests to use `doAsync` instead.

```
doAsync {
    val forecastWeather = ForecastRequest("302015").execute()
    uiThread {
        Log.d("Test", forecastWeather.toString())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23):

`async` is available inside [kotlinx.couroutines](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines)

Make sure that you added the dependency in your gradle file:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
```

Also make sure that the async is called on a coroutine scrope such as `GlobalScope`.

```
 val deferredResult = GlobalScope.async {

            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Different Kotlin libraries can have different implementations of `async` that do different things.

If you wanted the [general `async-await` function](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/f3042ac332fb79e7b71303538f6affb142195557/kotlinx-coroutines-core/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/Deferred.kt#L102) from the core library, make sure you have a dependency to [`kotlinx.coroutines`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Deferred , make sure you import kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred, there is also a chance you import firebase Deferred