# kotlin async doesn't compile

Tags: kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines, kotlin-experimental

The following code doesn't compile, although the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html) says it should be as simple as this:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    async {
        Log.d("foo", "async")
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
...kt: (31, 9): None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied:
@Deprecated public fun <T> async(context: CoroutineContext, start: Boolean, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> ???): Deferred<???> defined in kotlinx.coroutines.experimental
public fun <T> async(context: CoroutineContext, start: CoroutineStart = ..., block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> ???): Deferred<???> defined in kotlinx.coroutines.experimental
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Kotlin 1.2.41 (and yes, using Android)

Comment: @Zoe it needed a dependency: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use coroutines in an android app it is a must to add a dependency to `kotlinx-coroutines-android` as described [here](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines#android).

Answer (score 2):

If you compare signatures listed with https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.experimental/async.html, it's very different.

It looks like you are using an old version of coroutines library, and in particular one where `context` has no default value.

Answer (score 0):

Also, `async` function can only be used inside a coroutine or suspend function. So even if you have the correct dependencies, if you try to use `async` in onResume(), your code cannot compile.

Answer (score -3):

the `async{}` method is deprecated from [Kotlin 1.1](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew11.html) try:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    doAsync {
        Log.d("foo", "async")
    }
}
```

I suggest to you to read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44354505/5254885)

Comment: NOT deprecated, see the 3rd line of the error in my question; also see the official doc: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines.html

Comment: It's not deprecated. I have no clue where you see that. yes, the async method in Kotlin anko is deprecated, **but not the one in Kotlin coroutines**